# factorial in java using for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, factorial

```
 /* this program 
  * finds the factorial for any number
  */

public class forLoop1{

    public static void main(int x){    
        int init; 
        for( init = x; init < 2; init--){
            int finalint = init * --init; 
            System.out.println(finalint); 
        }
    }
}
```

^^ This program doesn't have an output, can anyone think of what's going wrong here? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If you only have one class and this is your only method called main, then you just don't have a entry point for the program, replace "int x" with "String[] args" and in your first line write "int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0)";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use command line argument then parse `String` to `int`.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int n=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int fac = 1;
    for(int i = n; i >= 2; i--) {
        fac = fac * i;
    }
    System.out.println(fac);
}
```

You should run this program as `java forLoop1 5` for an input `5` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You have problems at -- ummmm -- almost each line. Have a look at the code below and trace each step with n = 4 (or any other number).

```
public class forLoop1{
  public static void main(String[] args){    
    // n is the number whose factorial is to be calculated
    int n = 10; 
    int factorial = 1;
    for(int i = n; i >= 2; i--){
      factorial = factorial * i;
    }
    System.out.println(factorial);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class forLoop1{

 public static void main(String args[])
  { 
  System.out.println("Enter a number greater than zero.");
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  int n = in.nextInt();
  in.close();

  int fact = 1;
  for (n = n; n>=2; n--)
    fact *= n;

  System.out.println("Factorial of "+n+" is = "+fact);
  }
}
```

This should work. **Scanner** will read user input.

In your code, the loop will only execute if init is **less than** 2 to start with.

Here is an explanation of the errors in your code:

```
public static void main(int x){ //Should be public static void main(String[] args)       
    int init; 
    for( init = x; init < 2; init--){ //Should be init >= 2
        int finalint = init * --init; //Possibly should be init * (init - 1)
                                      //In each iteration of the loop,      
                                      //finalint will be overwritten
    System.out.println(finalint); //This line is fine.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, please look at my answer :)

Comment: @Aashirshukla You're welcome. Upvote if it helped you, and mark the answer you wrote as correct so others looking at the question know it's been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! Arjun, great your logic works perfectly 
A few things though: 
I do not need the `(String[] args)` part; I mentioned before too, as my IDE takes input for the `x` value by itself. So this is the code I used in the end:

```
  /* Factorial 
   * program
   */


public class forLoop2 {

    public void main(long x) { // long x is correct, as my IDE takes input through this 
        long fact = 1; 

        for( x = x; x >= 2; x--) 
            fact = fact * x; 

        System.out.println(fact); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The loop initializer `x=x` is redundant and can be skipped. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class forLoop1{
    public static void main(String args[]){ 

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number:");
        int x=input.nextInt();

        int finalint=1;
        for( int init=1;init<=x;init++){
            finalint=finalint*init;
        }
    }
}
```